# regexp to allow only one space in between words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to remove white spaces from just the beginning of the word, not after, and only a single space after the word.

Used RegExp:

```
var re = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)*$/);
```

Test Exapmle:

```
1) test[space]ing - Should be allowed 
2) testing - Should be allowed 
3) [space]testing - Should not be allowed 
4) testing[space] - Should be allowed but have to trim it 
5) testing[space][space] - should be allowed but have to trim it
```

Only one space should be allowed. Is it possible?

Comment: You're trying to match or to replace?

Comment: @sp00m i am just trying to match..

Comment: @MichalBrašna i want to allow the user to have one space in between.

Comment: should `a b c` be matched ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function validate(s) {
    if (/^(\w+\s?)*\s*$/.test(s)) {
        return s.replace(/\s+$/, '');
    }
    return 'NOT ALLOWED';
}
validate('test ing')    // => 'test ing'
validate('testing')     // => 'testing'
validate(' testing')    // => 'NOT ALLOWED'
validate('testing ')    // => 'testing'
validate('testing  ')   // => 'testing'
validate('test ing  ')  // => 'test ing'
```

BTW, `new RegExp(..)` is redundant if you use regular expression literal.

Comment: @coderman, I updated the answer. Previous answer matches only two words strings.

Comment: it is returning false for a valid "testing" input.

Comment: @coderman, It returns `true` for me. Maybe you're using older answer?

Comment: @coderman ya that should be `test[space]ing` and so ur answer will work fine.

Comment: @falsetru what is this .test(s) method here..I want to write the same thing in java.. is `test()` is similar to match ? Can i use directly `/^(\w+\s?)*\s*$/` regex in java or I have to remove that both start and end sticks (slash).

Comment: @Ranjit, Remove `^`, and `$`. (Slashes are parts of regular expression literal in javascript, also remove that.) And replace `\ ` with `\\ `. For more information, please post a separated question.

Answer (score 27):

To match, what you need, you can use

```
var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

Maybe you could shorten that a bit, but it matches `_` as well

```
var re = /^(\w+\s)*\w+$/;
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because it also allows single-letter matches.

Comment: @falsetru And that was the point as OP had `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)*` in regex

Comment: This perfectly worked!

Answer (score 6):

This one does not allow preceding and following spaces plus only one space between words. Feel free to add any special characters You want.

```
^([A-Za-z]+ )+[A-Za-z]+$|^[A-Za-z]+$
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pN8xL5/3)

Comment: If this is what you want, it can be simpler: `^[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+)*$`

Answer (score 1):

Working code- Inside my `name.addTextChangedListener()`:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String n = name.getText().toString();
            if (n.equals(""))
                name.setError("Name required");
            else if (!n.matches("[\\p{Alpha}\\s]*\\b") | n.matches(".*\\s{2}.*") | n.matches("\\s.*")) {
                if (n.matches("\\s.*"))
                    name.setError("Name cannot begin with a space");
                else if (n.matches(".*\\s{2}.*"))
                    name.setError("Multiple spaces between texts");
                else if (n.matches(".*\\s"))
                    name.setError("Blank space at the end of text");
                else
                    name.setError("Non-alphabetic character entered");
            }
        }
```

You could try adapting this to your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var f=function(t){return Math.pow(t.split(' ').length,2)/t.trim().split(' ').length==2}

f("a a")
true
f("a a ")
false
f("a  a")
false
f(" a a")
false
f("a a a")
false
```

Comment: Does it even work? This looks like its missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without regular expression.
Add this script inside document.ready function it will work.

```
var i=0;
        jQuery("input,textarea").on('keypress',function(e){
            //alert();
            if(jQuery(this).val().length < 1){
                if(e.which == 32){
                    //alert(e.which);
                return false;
                }   
            }
            else {
            if(e.which == 32){
                if(i != 0){
                return false;
                }
                i++;
            }
            else{
                i=0;
            }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChangeText = text => {
    let lastLetter = text[text.length - 1];
    let secondLastLetter = text[text.length - 2];
    if (lastLetter === ' ' && secondLastLetter === ' ') {
      return;
    }
    setInputText(text.trim());
  };
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain your solution.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
^([A-Za-z]{5,}|[\s]{1}[A-Za-z]{1,})*$
```

Demo:-https://regex101.com/r/3HP7hl/2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer]. Why should I, or anyone else for that matter, "use this"? Instead of adding such non-sentences, please [edit] the question to explain **why** this regex does what the OP wants to do. Always remember you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers (such as yourself, given this question is 6 years old)

Comment: The silly `{1}` is a dead giveaway, this is a stark regex beginner.