# regular expression for string allowing one whitespace

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I have this line as string:

`'10 NGBSDN60AQ\n Adafazef ajlafea jhaze  20 SSB 30BA\nqdfqd 40 ON 300 30\n'`

My Regex is `r'[0-9]{2,3}[\s]+[A-Z0-9\s]{6,12}\\n{1}'`

It identifies:

- 10 NGBSDN60AQ\n
- 20 SSB 30BA\n
- 40 ON 300 30\n

but i dont want last one, `40 ON 300 30\n`

I'd like to know how to get the second part of my regular expression
string between 6 and 12 characters (numbers or letters) that allows only one whitespace or not.

Comment: What's desired output

Comment: You say you want to get `20 SSB 30BA` though the requirements only allow 1 space in the match. Please review the requirements and update the question.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722081/regexp-to-allow-only-one-space-in-between-words

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following solution. **It does not use only regex** to give you the correct result, but it does the job:

```
import re

s = '10 NGBSDN60AQ\n Adafazef ajlafea jhaze  20 SSB 30BA\nqdfqd 40 ON 300 30\n'

my_regex = r'[0-9]{2,3}[\s]+[A-Z0-9\s]{6,12}\n{1}'
pattern = re.compile(my_regex)
result = pattern.findall(s)
result = [i for i in result if len(i.split()) < 4]

print(result)  # ['10 NGBSDN60AQ\n', '20 SSB 30BA\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regular expression solution, you may try with this:

`^[0-9]{2,3}[\s]+(?!=.* .* )(?=.{6,12}$)\w+(?: \w+)?$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/stXtgX/3/)**

**Explained**:

```
^                   # begin of line
    [0-9]{2,3}
    [\s]+
    (?!=.* .* )     # following text must not contain 2 spaces
    (?=.{6,12}$)    # following text must be 6 to 12 chars long
    \w+(?: \w+)?    # WORD and optional (space + WORD)
$
```

Comment: By the way, I leaved the original `[\s]+` of your regex. But it can be simply written as `\s+`