# How to make sure a user doesn't insert random spaces or repeated letters into a form in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms

I am trying to insert a validation into my Angular 9 app which doesn't let a user insert loads of spaces instead of a text into a form.

Currently, I have the below code but it doesn't let for any space. I would like the user to be able to insert a space but not just all spaces as I need useful data in my database. This example is an enquiry form for my website. I have the below code with the custom empty space validator but as mentioned it doesn't let me insert any space. The aim is here to not allow users enter content such as 20 empty spaces or random repeated letters such as `'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr'`.

Here is the code snippet I have but I think it will need to be changed altogether:

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
    export function NoWhitespaceValidator(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null {
        if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            return {cannotContainSpace: true}
        }
    return null;
}
```

Only solutions that I seem to find are just validators that don't allow a single space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per VeKri's help, I have done this in regular expressions way and the below are my results:

```js
Validators.pattern('^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\\1{3})(?! +$)[A-Za-z -]+$')
```

The first part makes sure that the same characters are not repeated more than 3 times in order to avoid input such as `'ddddddddddddd'`, while the second part (second pair of brackets) does not allow input of solely spaces to be inserted.

It was very useful to use a regular expressions tester such as https://regex101.com/ in order to play about with the expression.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if ((control.value as string).includes(' ')  && (control.value as string).indexOf(' ') != 0) {
return {cannotContainSpace: true}
}
```

Comment: try inside of the first if statment putting if( !(control.value as string).includes("  ")){

Comment: btw there is two spaces in that quote

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to find a way that a space after a single word is permitted but several spaces are not permitted. At the moment it doesn't allow a single space after a single word. Hope that makes sense. So pretty much how to ensure a user does not insert blank spaces into a database through the form

Comment: do you mean that after the first word there can be no more spaces?

Comment: sorry, I mean there should be a space after a word same as if you were to write this comment. So there shouldn't be a space on its own as an input. The input should be meaningful

Comment: so two or three spaces in a row would be invalid

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722081/regexp-to-allow-only-one-space-in-between-words

Answer (score 0):

We could even improve this RegExp for multiline validation as follows:

```js
const pattern = new RegExp('^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{3})(?! +$)[A-Za-z -]+$','m'); 

Validators.pattern(pattern);  //form control
```