# Javascript regular expression do not allow more than 1 consecutive spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to do a regular expression that does not allow more than 1
consecutive spaces.

For example:

- `A Bb 7` is valid
- `AA  O` is not valid
- `00 55`  is valid
- `A b`   is not valid

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722081/regexp-to-allow-only-one-space-in-between-words . It's very similar with what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```js
let str = "apple mango pine";

let result = str.match(/ {2,}/g);

if (result) {
  console.log("two consecutive spaces are not allowed");
} else console.log("valid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs I can provide two versions:

This works with only the "space" character, but does not take other spacing characters from Unicode into account:

```
^[^ ]*(?: [^ ]+)* ?$
```

That takes the regex spacing characters into account, so also uses newlines, tabs etc. as "space":

```
^\S*(?:\s\S+)*\s?$
```

Both regular expressions match when they find a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you need a regular expression for this?

```
 if (string.includes('  '))
    alert('error!')
```